# Getting no space between divs

Tags: html, .net, bootstrap-4

I am new to webforms and am trying to create a login page with 2 buttons and 2 textboxes. I have placed them between divs however I am getting no spces between them.

Here is what I am getting:
[image]

As you can see there is no vertical space between the buttons and textboxes and labels

Here is the code I am using:

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">

                <div class="card">
                   <div class="card-body">
                      
                       <div class="row">
                           <div class="col">
                              <center>
                               <img width="150px" src="imgs/generaluser.png" />
                              </center>
                           </div>
                       </div>

                       <div class="row">
                           <div class="col">
                              <center>
                               <h3>Member Login</h3>
                              </center>
                           </div>
                       </div>

                       <div class="row">
                           <div class="col">
                              <center>
                               <hr>
                              </center>
                           </div>
                       </div>

                       <div class="row">
                           <div class="col">
                              
                               <label>Member ID</label>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <asp:TextBox  CssClass= "form-control" ID="Textbox1" runat="server" 
                               placeholder="Member ID"></asp:TextBox>
                              </div>

                              
                               <label>Password</label>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <asp:TextBox  CssClass= "form-control" ID="Textbox2" runat="server" 
                               placeholder="Password" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                              </div>

                               <div class="form-group">
                                   <asp:Button  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg col-12" ID="Button1"  
                               runat="server" Text="Login" />
                              </div>

                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <input class="btn btn-info btn-lg col-12" id="Button2" 
                               type="button" value="Sign Up" />
                              </div>
                             
                           </div>
                       </div>

                   </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

I am using bootstrap. Should not it give vertical space automatically?

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why not add a [padding class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)? For example `.pb-3` to add padding to the bottom of a div

Comment: Are you using any additional styling besides bootstrap ? I've used the fragment you supplied and added a reference to Bootstrap 4 and the form fields and buttons have spaces between them.

Comment: I am using Custom css for the footer

Comment: Does the custom css contain style for the `div` and `label` tag that perhaps removes the margin which Bootstrap put there ? Try the page with no style sheets except Bootstrap.

Comment: no it doesnt it contains styling for the footer

Answer (score 0):

You can add margin with bootstrap by adding it to the class

```
<label class="mt-3">Password</label>
```

You should be using inputs instead of textboxes
and you should look into wrapping it all in a form

```
<head>
  <!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">

                <div class="card">
                   <div class="card-body">
                      
                       <div class="row">
                           <div class="col">
                              <center>
                               <img width="150px" src="imgs/generaluser.png" />
                              </center>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="row">
                           <div class="col">
                              <center>
                               <h3>Member Login</h3>
                              </center>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="row">
                           <div class="col">
                              <center>
                               <hr>
                              </center>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="row">
                           <div class="col">
                               <label>Member ID</label>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <input class= "form-control" ID="Textbox1" runat="server" 
                               placeholder="Member ID"></T>
                              </div>
                               <label class="mt-3">Password</label>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <input class= "form-control" ID="Textbox2" runat="server" 
                               placeholder="Password" TextMode="Password"></Textarea>
                              </div>
                               <div class="form-group mt-2">
                                   <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg col-12" ID="Button1"  
                               runat="server" Text="Login" value="Login" />
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group mt-2">
                                  <input class="btn btn-info btn-lg col-12" id="Button2" 
                               type="button" value="Sign Up" />
                              </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>

                   </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a `margin-top` for the button class  of use a `<br>` after the first button container